# Mysql table integration with maximo db2

Tags: integration, jira, maximo

I have a requirement with Maximo 7.5 integration  with MySQL database as inbound.

Can any one help me how to go further.

We have two ticketing system one is Maximo and other is Jira, which needs to integrate ticket details of jira with Maximo.

How can I use Maximo integration framework for this inbound integration?

Comment: For a direct database link you can review this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453301/configuring-mysql-linked-server-with-db2



You can also get data into Maximo using flat files, XML, interface tables... web services, REST API:

http://www.xcentricway.ca/tutorial08.htm

Comment: Hi W Kim, I Will get back to you with output, further help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maximo comes with Maximo Integration framework (MIF)

You should check if you have the security rights to use it by checking :

1. click on `GOTO`
2. See if you have an option Integration.

these links might help:

1. this [wiki](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Integration%20Framework) has some nice information from IBM itself
2. this [post](http://maximodev.blogspot.com/p/integration-framework.html) from Bruno is a good starting point also
3. and not to forget [Maximo flat file export](http://www.maximopulse.com/2014/07/16/basics-of-maximo-integration-framework-steps-for-flat-file-export/)